# Unable to use RSpec::Matchers with binding.pry

Tags: ruby, debugging, cucumber, pry, site-prism

I'm working with Cucumber, Ruby and SitePrism classes. I was trying to make assertions inside the SitePrism classes and I manage to use the 'expectation' methods when including RSpec::Matchers, however, I was using 'binding.pry' for debugging and I've just now noticed that I am not able to use it anymore as it keeps of failing with the following error:

> NoMethodError: private method `print' called for #RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Output:0x0000000a5536b0>
>   Did you mean?  printf
>                  sprintf

Do you know what the error could be? I've tried different ways to include RSpec::Matchers, so not sure if I'm doing something the wrong way?

```
*Method 1:*
include RSpec::Matchers
class SitePrismPage

*Method 2:*
class SitePrismPage
    extend RSpec::Matchers

*Method 3:*
class SitePrismPage
end
World{SitePrismPage.new}
```

Comment: we need the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not much code... ie, one class that needs to use expectations (so I was including the RSpec::Matchers in one of the 3 ways above). Then, it doesn't matter where I put the 'binding.pry' command (in the step definitions, inside the class, etc)... whenever I use that command for debugging, now the tests fail with the error about 'printf sprintf' :S

Comment: Is there at least a stack trace?  I'm looking through the Pry source code but a trace could help narrow it down.

Comment: I was running the tests from the command line in verbose mode, and there's nothing else that Ruby outputs. Just the step/file.rb file wherever 'binding.pry' is put and the message error about 'private method print called'. I don't know what I could try to workaround the issue, as at present this means I cannot put any assertion inside a SitePrism class... so my steps can become quite untidy if I need to move all my methods outside.

Answer (score 1):

*Old question but providing extra info*

Whilst there's not enough code here to make a judgement, if you're following the SitePrism guide then perform your testing in the step_definitions doesn't require you to include or load anything.

All 3 of your setups aren't required. Simply require the requisite files in your `env.rb` file and you're good to go.

This enables you to have fairly clean tests but also keeping anything extra from being mixed into places it shouldn't be.

Dependent on who you speak to, it is intended to perform all testing in the Cucumber World and all Modelling work in the support code (But that's a question for another day)